# Xubuntu 14.04 setting Primary Monitors

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, xubuntu, multiple-monitors, xfce

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04 with the 331.38 drivers that I installed via the "Additional Drivers"

My issue is that when ever I start up a game it starts up in the wrong monitor, to fix this I when my computer starts I set the primary monitor in the Nvidia settings manager.. the only problem is every reboot it looses the setting of the primary monitor... and I have to keep setting this every time.

I notice there is no more Xorg file... so how would I fix this seeing that the Display settings of XFCE is not able to set "Primary Monitor"

Answer (score 1):

use `xrandr` and find the display you want to set as primary, then
in your `.bashrc` add the command

```
xrandr --output [DISPLAY DEVINCE] --primary
```

Example:

```
xrandr --output DP-1 --primary
```

this is the same as going into the nvidia-settings app and applying a primary monitor. 
log out and log back in, and you should see that your primary monitor is set correctly.